# Pinch gesture does not work if view registers pan gesture

Tags: ios, uikit, uigesturerecognizer

I have an app that manipulates view with gestures. View is connected to pan, pinch and rotate gestures. If I start interacting with the view with two fingers all gestures are working simultaneously (expected behavior). But if you start with one finger pan, pinch and rotate gestures do not work. None of the methods in the delegate are called when I am trying to start pinch or rotate while panning.

```
shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith
```

is always true.

Expected behavior,

1. one finger pan on the view
2. add second finger and start pinch/rotate interaction
   (similar to instagram stories editor)

Comment: Did you also try and play around with `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin`?

Comment: @MaticOblak Yes, even if I put always true it does not work. I believe there is a problem switching between one finger to two finger gestures. It seems that second finger touch is not getting recognized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a clean project I added the following:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        view.addGestureRecognizer({
            let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onPan))
            gesture.delegate = self
            return gesture
        }())
        view.addGestureRecognizer({
            let gesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onPinch))
            gesture.delegate = self
            return gesture
        }())
        view.addGestureRecognizer({
            let gesture = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onRotate))
            gesture.delegate = self
            return gesture
        }())
    }
    
    @objc private func onPan(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Did pan to \(sender.translation(in: sender.view))")
    }
    
    @objc private func onPinch(_ sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Did pinch to \(sender.scale)")
    }
    
    @objc private func onRotate(_ sender: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Did rotate to: \(sender.rotation)")
    }


}

extension ViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    
    func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool { true }
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool { true }
    
}
```

All 3 methods report changes after the scenario you described:

- I started with single touch drag gesture
- I pressed another finger and started rotating gesture and pinching gesture

Does already this example not work for you? What is the behavior you are experiencing and what is expected behavior?

Comment: Your example does work. However, the issue in code was in a broken view hierarchy in my controller.